# Resize container to window height with max-width

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to build a page with a wrapper that would be max-width: 700px

Optimally, the page would be responsive and resize the images to fit the window. I'm really having a difficult time getting the browser to resize the images and container to fit the window height. Width seems to scale just fine. Ultimately, the user wouldn't have to scroll down to see the page. Is this possible without JavaScript? If not, can someone point me in the right direction? Thanks! Code as follows:

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LTchE/

```
<style type="text/css">
body, html {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px auto;
    padding: 0px auto;
}
#wrapper {
    height: auto;
    min-height: 100%;
    margin: 0px auto;
    padding: 0px auto;
    max-width: 600px;
    background: #de291e;
}
.happyHolidays {
    background: url('http://placehold.it/600x80') no-repeat center;
    background-size: contain;
    width: 90%;
    height: 80px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
}
.fromMe {
    background: url('http://placehold.it/600x80') no-repeat center;
    background-size: contain;
    width: 90%;
    height: 80px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
}
.buttons {
    text-align: center;
}
.snowperson {
    text-align: center;
}
.snowperson img {
    width: 100%;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="happyHolidays"></div>
    <div class="fromMe"></div>
    <div class="snowperson">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/650x750" name="snowperson" border=0>
    </div>
    <div class="buttons">
        <a href="javascript:NextImage()">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/150x50" alt="Next snowperson">
        </a>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up adding some styling to the wrapper:

```
#wrapper {
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: #de291e;
    background-image: url('../images/snowbg.png');
    background-repeat: repeat;
    min-width: 600px;
    max-width: 700px;
    min-height: calc(690px * (90/150));
    height: 90vh;
    width: 150vh;
    max-height: 890px;
    position: relative;

}
```

This works relatively well for my situation... thought it's still not perfect.

You can see the final at www.ogilvypr.com/happyholidays

Answer (score 0):

Use the Overflow:hidden To the wrapper class 
Give the Wrapper class to the overflow:hidden your scroll is hidden

Answer (score 0):

The key is, in order for #wrapper to 'inherit' 100% height from the browser, all its parent elements (including the HTML tag) need to be position:relative; and height 100%;

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      html, body, .wrap {
        position:relative;
        height:100%;
        margin:0;
      }
      .wrap {
        max-width:700px;
        margin:0 auto;
        background:#aaa;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="wrap">Test Text</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I threw it up temporarily on my server here: http://mechapps.co/fullheight/

And, here's your code: http://mechapps.co/fullheight/overflown.html

Comment: The goal is so that the container resizes vertically, though. So if you were to resize the height of the viewport, the content would adjust to the size of the viewport and take up 100% of the height of the viewport while obeying the width of the wrapper. Your example does not appear to be doing that for me in Chrome.

Comment: Ah, quite right. I didn't quite have your code working. If you look at the second link above, it will work now.

To be more specific, the container #wrapper scales horizontally, but it's contents overflow off the bottom of the page. If you want to scale the content vertically so that the center of the image is in the center of the browser, I can show you how to do that too.

Comment: Yeah, the goal is to scale vertically as well... it should be totally responsive to window size.

Comment: Vertically responsive websites are tricky. Couple questions: 1. do you want the header (top two images) to always be 160px? 2. do you want the snowman picture to be vertically centered in the browser, or vertically centered in the space under the header?